# How to Query MongoDB with Multiple AND Conditions for Phone Numbers using FilterDefinition in C#?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, multiple-conditions

I have a MongoDB collection named "Applicants" with documents containing information about applicants, including their last name, type, and an array of phone numbers with different types like "home", "cell", and "office."

Here's a sample JSON representation of an "Applicant" document:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("61791ecf2abf206fd5e5e322"),
  "LastName": "Smith",
  "Type": "P",
  "PhoneNumbers": [
    { "Type": "home", "Value": "111-111-1111" },
    { "Type": "cell", "Value": "222-222-2222" },
    { "Type": "office", "Value": "333-333-3333" }
  ]
}
```

Now, I need to perform a query to find applicants with specific phone numbers, e.g., "home" and "cell" phone numbers. I am using the MongoDB C# driver and want to use FilterDefinition for this purpose.

I have tried using ElemMatch method with multiple conditions, but it doesn't seem to work as expected. Here's my current attempt:

```
var filterBuilder = Builders<Applicant>.Filter;
var homePhoneFilter = filterBuilder.Eq("PhoneNumbers.Type", "home") & filterBuilder.Eq("PhoneNumbers.Value", "111-111-1111");
var cellPhoneFilter = filterBuilder.Eq("PhoneNumbers.Type", "cell") & filterBuilder.Eq("PhoneNumbers.Value", "222-222-2222");
var queryFilter = homePhoneFilter & cellPhoneFilter;
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't return any results, and I suspect that combining the homePhoneFilter and cellPhoneFilter using & might not be the right approach.

Rendered Query:

Following is expected render query

```
{
  "PhoneNumbers": {
    "$elemMatch": { "$and": [ { "Type": "home" }, { "Value": "111-111-1111" } ], "$and": [ { "Type": "cell" }, { "Value": "222-222-2222" } ] }
  }
}
```

Any guidance on how to correctly implement multiple AND conditions using FilterDefinition in C# for my MongoDB query would be highly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: You're right to use `$elemMatch` but you've placed it too high. The top level should be an `$and` which contains two `$elemMatch` objects (each of which checks for a single pair of `Type` and `Value` conditions)

Comment: Yes that could also work but  if you try to see performance for 1miillion record two $elemMatch will be 10time slower

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with @user20042973's comment, your query is incorrect. It should be:

**Solution 1**

```
db.collection.find({
  $and: [
    {
      PhoneNumbers: {
        "$elemMatch": {
          "Type": "home",
          "Value": "111-111-1111"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      PhoneNumbers: {
        "$elemMatch": {
          "Type": "cell",
          "Value": "222-222-2222"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

[Demo Solution 1 @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/W8FHLiSGTZo)

For MongoDB .NET syntax:

```cs
var filterBuilder = Builders<Applicant>.Filter;

var homePhoneFilter = filterBuilder.ElemMatch(
    x => x.PhoneNumbers,
    y => y.Type == "home" && y.Value == "111-111-1111");
                
var cellPhoneFilter = filterBuilder.ElemMatch(
    x => x.PhoneNumbers,
    y => y.Type == "cell" && y.Value == "222-222-2222"); 

var queryFilter = homePhoneFilter & cellPhoneFilter;
```

---

**Solution 2: Working with [$all](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/all/) operator**

> The `$all` operator selects the documents where the value of a field is an array that contains all the specified elements.

```
db.collection.find({
  PhoneNumbers: {
    $all: [
      {
        $elemMatch: {
          "Type": "home",
          "Value": "111-111-1111"
        }
      },
      {
        $elemMatch: {
          "Type": "cell",
          "Value": "222-222-2222"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

[Demo Solution 2 @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/IhwIOoymlpF)

For MongoDB .NET syntax:

```cs
var filterBuilder = Builders<Applicant>.Filter;
var queryFilter = filterBuilder.All(x => x.PhoneNumbers, new List<PhoneNumber>
{
    new PhoneNumber { Type = "home", Value = "111-111-1111" },
    new PhoneNumber { Type = "cell", Value = "222-222-2222" }
});
```

Comment: 2 mention solution will work but if you compare it with the expected query which i mention there is huge performance gap when number of record are 1million+ .  The one i sent is possible to generate using Bsondocument but dont know how to do it with FilterDefinition.

Comment: MongoDB .NET Driver does support the [implicit conversion from `BsonDocument`](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.0/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_FilterDefinition_1_op_Implicit.htm).